# Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Jujutsu Kaisen anime end in?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

If you want to keep following Jujutsu Kaisen story in the manga, after the first season of the anime ended, you need to know which chapter of the manga the anime ends.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Jujutsu Kaisen anime end in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Chapter 63.** According to https://latestnews.fresherslive.com,

> Chapter 63 of Jujutsu Kaisen was adapted for the season one finale. The narrative concludes the Death Painting arc, which is included in volume eight.